# Copy selected text from one document and paste to new document in same position on the page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was looking for a long time but unfortunately I cannot get a clear answer anywhere.

What I need is to copy selected text from one word document than open new document and paste the text to new document but in the exactly same position in the page as the original text.

Here is what I done so far:

```
Sub Patient()

Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Please select text to copy", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Info")

If answer = vbYes Then
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add _
 Name:="myplace", Range:=Selection.Range

     Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="myplace"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
    Selection.Copy
    Documents.Add Template:="Normal", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
    Windows.CompareSideBySideWith "Test_Document.docx"
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
 Else
  MsgBox "Please highlight the text first", 16
End If

End Sub
```

So what I done:
1- force the user to select the text to copy, if no selection is  made the error message will appears.
2- set the bookmark to name "myplace"
3- copy the bookmark
4- open the new document
4- set the view side by side
5- paste the bookmark text to new document
6- I was manually formatting the text using enter to get it to required location so I can print it on existing paper.

What I need is that the selected text will by pasted to exact location on the page as original.
The original text selection can be anywhere on the page, depends on what the user selects.

I also found that the MS Word can count start and end of my bookmark so I was hoping we can write the VBA to position of pasted text exactly where the original bookmark was:

```
Sub Count()
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("myplace")
MsgBox .Range.Start & vbTab & .Range.End
End With
End Sub
```

Let me describe what I am trying to achieve and why I need this function.

I have a patient record, where I write basic info about the patient like name, address, telephone number etc., and then I have therapy where I describe all the symptoms and progress what the patient make trough time.

I than print the document and store it in cabinet as hard copy, as this is legal requirements.
The patient may have many visits, so I keep adding the info to the existing record and each time I need to print it.

In order to save paper, I would like to have only the new added text to be printed on the same document I printed already. I always put the existing doc back to printer.
I know that the MS Word offers print selection option but when selected text is printed, it is always printed on top of the document and this will print over my existing text.

So what I was trying to do is select the required text, assign bookmark, copy bookmark, open new document, paste the text, set the view side by side and then I was manually formatting the text using enter to get it to required location so I can print it on existing paper.

Is there any other way to achieve this than VBA?

I would be grateful for any advice or help.

Many thanks,
Peter.

Comment: Word is a word processor. Pages are not VBA objects, so the position of text on a page requires a fair bit of calculation. Then to place that same text in the same place on a different page would require you to put it in a text box and position that text box. To make the position exact will require an extraordinary programming effort.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44925-copy-selected-text-one-document-paste-new.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184. I don't know why you think cross-posting is going to change the answer...

Comment: Hi, I just simply did not know that it is the same forum, or it is cross-posting. Shall I remove the post?